# How should i return Qt::WindowFlags in a function

Tags: c++, qt

when i write a function :

```
    static inline Qt::WindowFlags windowFlags()
    {
        return Qt::Window | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint;
    }
```

i get error:
`error: no viable conversion from returned value of type 'unsigned int' to function return type 'Qt::WindowFlags' (aka 'QFlags<Qt::WindowType>')`
How should i do? Best wish for your help.

Comment: What version of Qt are you using?  Qt defines operator overloads explicitly to address this kind of problem.  If you are targeting multiple versions of Qt, you can do a version-check and define the operator yourself if the version is too old.

Comment: Either return `unsigned int` or `static_cast` the return value to `Qt::WindowFlags`.